# Помогите с вопросом структуры проекта

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение в котором есть активности классов (в общем не важно каких, но планируется много), сделать много или как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делать отдельный класс для каждой страны это не правильно. Ведь у всех стран есть похожие характеристики. Есть столица, есть список регионов, есть физические величины, такие например как площадь или длина границы, есть экономические и демографические характеристики и т.д. 
Сделай абстрактный класс с базовым функционалом и расширяй интерфейсами по мере необходимости.

Comment: Тоже уже решил так делать и придумал как решить мою задачу

Comment: @Shadowlight ну и для навигации в данном случае просто передавать с одного фрагмента на второй id и по этому id выводить всю информацию. Сдесь вообще 1 активити можно обойтись